# como recorrer u obtener los valores de un reciclerView en android?

Tags: android

Tengo un lista de clientes que la muestro en un `reciclerView` personalizado, esa lista tienes unos `Editext` de los cuales necesito obtener el valor, encontré unos ejemplos pero no me funcionan:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(i);
            EditText text = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
        }
```

Me arroja  el siguiente error:

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object
```

se que me reciclerView no es null ya que esta mostrando una lista en pantalla

si hago esto:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <data ; i++) {
            View view = mRecyclerView.getRootView();
            Log.i("layout",view.toString());
            TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
            String nm = name.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.i("nombre",nm);
        }
```

Solo me trae el primer nombre de la lista 5 veces

Mi clase adaptador:

```
public class ClienteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClienteAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Cliente> mClienteList;
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;

/**
 * Constructs a new {@link ClienteAdapter}
 *
 * @param context     of the app
 * @param ClienteList is the list of Cliente, which is the data source of the adapter
 */
public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> ClienteList) {
    mContext = context;
    mClienteList = ClienteList;
}

@Override
public ClienteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cliente_card_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mClienteList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleTextView;
    private TextView sectionTextView;
    private TextView authorTextView;
    private TextView dateTextView;
    private ImageView shareImageView;
    private ImageView btnPedido;
    private ImageView btnCheckin;
    private TextView trailTextView;
    private CardView cardView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
        sectionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card);
        authorTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_card);
        dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_card);
        shareImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMaps);
        btnCheckin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckin);
        btnPedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPedido);
        trailTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trail_text_card);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    // Change the color theme of Title TextView by using the user's stored preferences

    // Change text size of TextView by using the user's stored preferences
    setTextSize(holder);

    // Find the current Cliente that was clicked on
    final Cliente currentCliente = mClienteList.get(position);

    holder.titleTextView.setText(currentCliente.getNombre());
    holder.sectionTextView.setText(currentCliente.getRazonSocial());
    // If the author does not exist, hide the authorTextView
    if (currentCliente.getNombre() == null) {
        holder.authorTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.authorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.authorTextView.setText(currentCliente.getDepartamento()+" - "+currentCliente.getMunicipio());
    }

    // Get time difference between the current date and web publication date and
    // set the time difference on the textView
    holder.dateTextView.setText(formatDate(currentCliente.getFechaHoraCreacion()));

    // Get string of the trailTextHTML and convert Html text to plain text
    // and set the plain text on the textView
    holder.trailTextView.setText(currentCliente.getDireccion());
    if (currentCliente.getLatitud()>0){
        holder.shareImageView.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);
    }

    // Set an OnClickListener to open a website with more information about the selected article
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), ClienteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cliente",currentCliente);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    // Set an OnClickListener to share the data with friends via email or  social networking
    holder.shareImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
    holder.btnPedido.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int idCliente = currentCliente.getId();
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), OrdenActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cliente",currentCliente);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    holder.btnCheckin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), CheckinActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("cliente",currentCliente);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

/**
 * Set the user preferred color theme
 */


/**
 * Set the text size to the text size the user choose.
 */
private void setTextSize(ViewHolder holder) {
    // Get the text size string from SharedPreferences and check for the value associated with the key
    String textSize = sharedPrefs.getString(
            mContext.getString(R.string.settings_text_size_key),
            mContext.getString(R.string.settings_text_size_default));

    // Change text size of TextView by using the user's stored preferences
    if (textSize.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_text_size_medium_value))) {
        holder.titleTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp22));
        holder.sectionTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp14));
        holder.trailTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp16));
        holder.authorTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp14));
        holder.dateTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp14));
    } else if (textSize.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_text_size_small_value))) {
        holder.titleTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp20));
        holder.sectionTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp12));
        holder.trailTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp14));
        holder.authorTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp12));
        holder.dateTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp12));
    } else if (textSize.equals(mContext.getString(R.string.settings_text_size_large_value))) {
        holder.titleTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp24));
        holder.sectionTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp16));
        holder.trailTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp18));
        holder.authorTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp16));
        holder.dateTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sp16));
    }
}



/**
 * Clear all data (a list of {@link Cliente} objects)
 */
public void clearAll() {
    mClienteList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Add  a list of {@link Cliente}
 *
 * @param ClienteList is the list of Cliente, which is the data source of the adapter
 */
public void addAll(List<Cliente> ClienteList) {
    mClienteList.clear();
    mClienteList.addAll(ClienteList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Convert date and time in UTC (webPublicationDate) into a more readable representation
 * in Local time
 *
 * @param dateStringUTC is the web publication date of the article (i.e. 2014-02-04T08:00:00Z)
 * @return the formatted date string in Local time(i.e "Jan 1, 2000  2:15 AM")
 * from a date and time in UTC
 */
private String formatDate(String dateStringUTC) {
    // Parse the dateString into a Date object
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
    Date dateObject = null;
    try {
        dateObject = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStringUTC);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Initialize a SimpleDateFormat instance and configure it to provide a more readable
    // representation according to the given format, but still in UTC
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy  h:mm a");
    String formattedDateUTC = df.format(dateObject);
    // Convert UTC into Local time
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(formattedDateUTC);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return df.format(date);
}

/**
 * Get the formatted web publication date string in milliseconds
 *
 * @param formattedDate the formatted web publication date string
 * @return the formatted web publication date in milliseconds
 */
private static long getDateInMillis(String formattedDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
            new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy  h:mm a");
    long dateInMillis;
    Date dateObject;
    try {
        dateObject = simpleDateFormat.parse(formattedDate);
        dateInMillis = dateObject.getTime();
        return dateInMillis;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Problem parsing date", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, acabo de ver tu pregunta, lo que deseas es obtener los valores  los ReciclerView que estos a su vez están en una lista verdad?, ¿tienes un objeto con el cual llenas las propiedades de cada elemento en el listado de elementos?

Comment: la lista de objetos la creo con datos que vienen de un ws, no le agrego items al reciclerview solo lo contruyo con datos que ya tengo, agregue mi clase del recicler view

Comment: lo que deseo es editar unos datos y tomar el valor de esos textview que estaran en el recicler view

Comment: Ok @IgmerRodriguez , considera crear un lista de objetos de los datos que obtienes del WS, si deseas tomar los valores de los TextView que se encuentran en las vistas del RecyclerView esto no es adecuado ya que algunas vistas pueden "no existir" si no hasta que las ves en pantalla, mejor obten los valores de la lista de objetos creados a partir de la respuesta del WS.

Comment: Cuando generas un recycler view, lleva un adapter que es el que controla la información de los datos, ese adapter tiene como entrada una lista del modelo de datos, y los itera en el ViewHolder asigna los valores, pon un punto de interrupción, para que veas como se llena la información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude responder a mi pregunta, haciendo lo siguiente:

1. comprender que un `reciclerView` se va creando en tiempo de ejecución, (cuando haces scroll) por lo tanto no es posible recorrerlo y obtener todos los valores que se van a mostrar ya que solo existen hasta que se muestran en pantalla
2. La clase  del reciclerView recibe una lista de objetos que si se puede modificar

aca dejo mi clase adaptador:

```
public class ClienteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ClienteAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Cliente> mClienteList;
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

/**
 * Constructs a new {@link ClienteAdapter}
 *
 * @param context     of the app
 * @param ClienteList is the list of Cliente, which is the data source of the adapter
 */
public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> ClienteList) {
    mContext = context;
    mClienteList = ClienteList; //recibe una lista de objetos de tipo Ccliente
}

@Override
public ClienteAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cliente_card_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mClienteList.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView titleEditext;
    private TextView sectionTextView;
    private TextView authorTextView;
    private TextView dateTextView;
    private ImageView shareImageView;
    private ImageView btnPedido;
    private ImageView btnCheckin;
    private TextView trailTextView;
    private CardView cardView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        //obtengo los elementos que estan el la vista que se usara como plantilla
        titleEditext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
        sectionTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.section_card);
        authorTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.author_card);
        dateTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_card);
        shareImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMaps);
        btnCheckin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckin);
        btnPedido = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPedido);
        trailTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.trail_text_card);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    //para que no se pierda la posicion que se esta creando se debe usar la propiedad setTag()
    holder.itemView.setTag(position);

    //este metodo se ejecuta cuando se crea el elemento del recicler view,
    // recibe una posicion del elemento en la lsita de objetos y la vista que se crea
    final Cliente currentCliente = mClienteList.get(position);
    //obtengo el nombre del objeto en la posicion x
    holder.titleEditext.setText(currentCliente.getNombre());
    //le asigno al editext el evento  setOnFocusChangeListener que se ejecutara al momento que
    //el editext pierda o reciba el foco
    holder.titleEditext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            //en mi caso necesito obtener el valor cuando se pierda el foco
            if (!hasFocus) {
                //ahora edito el objeto en la pocicion que se cambio el texto
                //y asigno ese nuevo texto a la propiedad nombre del objeto cliente
                mClienteList.get(position).setNombre(holder.titleEditext.getText().toString().trim());

            }
        }
    });

}
// ahora ya tengo mi lista de objetos con los cambios que necesito, pero necesito usar esa lista en mi actividad
//para poder enviarla a un ws, lo que hice fue crear un metodo que me retorne la lista de onjetos

public final List<Cliente> retrieveData() {
    return mClienteList;
}
```

}

Comment: Hola, esto es lo que comentaba en mi respuesta, es en realidad lo que se realiza al usar un adapter cuyos elementos modifican sus propiedades, no te sirvió mi respuesta?

Answer (score 3):

Estas tratando de obtener los valores que se agregan a los `RecyclerView`, en el primer caso obtienes el error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
>   'android.view.View
>   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a
>   null object

esto se debe a que en realidad no tienes todos las vistas creadas en tu RecyclerView, recuerda que precisamente esto evita tener vistas en memoria innecesariamente, de hecho si la vista sale de pantalla, esta es eliminada, y al entrar en pantalla se crea o se recicla nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por esta razón al tratar de hacer referencia a un elemento que no existe obtienes un `NullPointerException`.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(i);
            EditText text = holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
            String text = textView.getText().toString();
        }
```

En el segundo caso, comentas que únicamente obtienes el primer nombre de la lista 5 veces, esto se debe a que estas haciendo referencia en realidad a la misma vista.

```
for (int i = 0; i <data ; i++) {
            View view = mRecyclerView.getRootView();
            Log.i("layout",view.toString());
            TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.title_card);
            String nm = name.getText().toString().trim();
            Log.i("nombre",nm);
        }
```

---

En cuanto a tu pregunta:

**¿como recorrer u obtener los valores de un RecyclerView en android?**

En este caso la mejor aproximación es **obtener los valores directamente de los objetos que agregan los valores a las vistas generadas por el `RecyclerView` en tu Adapter y no de las vistas creadas ya que algunos de estos elementos pueden no existir al no ser visibles en pantalla.**

Crea objetos para llenar tu Adapter y de aquí obtén las propiedades de cada elemento en el listado.

Comment: entonces no podria obtener el valor de los elementos que estan en el recilervier? son 200 item, no podria obtenerlos porque no estan en pantalla?

Comment: Exactamente Igmer, lo ideal es obtenerlos directamente de los objetos que llenan ese listado mediante el Adapter.

Comment: pero si pongo un editext que el usuario ingrese el valor como obtengo ese valor depues?

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez ah! en este caso ese valor en el EditText lo obtienes y lo guardas en el objeto, para que cuando realices scroll y este desaparezca de pantalla y posteriormente vuelvas a regresar a ese elemento, tome el valor editado desde el objeto y lo muestre nuevamente en el EditText.

Comment: ok voy a ver como obtengo ese valor del editext

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez de hecho acabo de ver tu Adapter que recibe una lista de objetos "Cliente", llamada ClienteList, entonces será fácil realizar el cambio y lo que deseas originalmente.

Comment: es que mi idea era mostrar los datos y poner un editext que el usario lo modifique, ese editext esta el vista del recicler view, creo que con un textwacher tendria que obtner ese valor verdad

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100160/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-igmer-rodriguez).