# Estoy usandro android Estudio ¿Como validar si los checkbox de mi listView estan marcados?

Tags: java, android

tengo un Listview con textbox y checkbox y al final un boton, necesito que al presionar el boton, valide si todos los checkbox estan marcados o no, ayuden porfavor.

Estoy trabajando con android studio

este es mi adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final  ViewHolder holder;
    final Cotizacion rowItem = (Cotizacion) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.checkHolder = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        holder.textCodProd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCodPro);
        holder.textProducto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtProducto);
        holder.textUnidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUnidad);
        holder.textCantidad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidad);
        holder.textLote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLote);
        holder.textFechaVen = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtFechaven);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.checkHolder.setChecked(rowItem.checkCoti);
    holder.textProducto.setText(rowItem.producto);
    holder.textCodProd.setText(rowItem.codProducto);
    holder.textUnidad.setText(rowItem.unidad);
    holder.textCantidad.setText(rowItem.cantidad);
    holder.textLote.setText(rowItem.lote);
    holder.textFechaVen.setText(rowItem.fechaVencimiento);


    return convertView;
}
```

}

[image: Adjunto un pedazo de mi adapter porque no me deja pegar todo el codigo]

Comment: Añade el código que tienes hasta ahora en tu pregunta. Revisa [ask]

Comment: tendras alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar el mètodo [isChecked()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html), ejemplo:

```
     CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_id);
     if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
         //Esta seleccionado
     }
```

Pero en el caso de un Adapter debes guardar el valor de cual elemento fue checado y de esta forma usar `setChecked()` para mostrar el valor en el listado.

Revisa la segunda parte de esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/302770/95)

"En este caso la mejor aproximación es obtener los valores directamente de los objetos que agregan los valores a las vistas generadas por el RecyclerView en tu Adapter y no de las vistas creadas ya que algunos de estos elementos pueden no existir al no ser visibles en pantalla.

Crea objetos para llenar tu Adapter y de aquí obtén las propiedades de cada elemento en el listado."

Answer (score 1):

La clase publica "CheckBox" cuenta con métodos heredados de la clase "CompoundButton", lo que quiere decir que puede acceder a estos métodos para realizar diferentes acciones. Para una revisión de todos sus método te invito a visitar la documentación oficial:
[Android Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox)

Para tu caso, para realizar la verificación que buscas utilizarías el método "isChecked()" este te regresara un valor de tipo Boolean:

true -> si el CheckBox esta marcado

false -> el CheckBox no esta marcado

Ejemplo:

```
if(checkHolder.isChecked()){
System.out.println("checkBox marcado");
}
```